# Raspberry Pi IR Receiver Software

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, infrared

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi to take a picture using a camera when a button on an IR blaster is pressed, and I do not want to use media center software. How do I program the IR part?

Comment: If you don't have an IR receiver already, I would suggest purchasing a FLIRC. It's USB, and will allow you to program any remote to send any keyboard press to your PI, which essentially turns your remotes into wireless keyboards. If you do already have an IR receiver, then you'll need to check out program LIRC (Decent instructables here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Universal-Remote/)

Comment: And then to connect the two (if using FLIRC hardware, not 100% with the LIRC route): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13434/thd-triggerhappy-global-hotkey-daemon-necessary

Comment: This question **might** be a better fit at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`LIRC`, *Linux Infrared Remote Control*, is an open source project that you can utilize to configure and read various IR commands from pretty much any remote control you have lying around. Project site: http://www.lirc.org

---

You can use cheap IR Recievers, available for less than $2 Dollars US. Like this one: http://www.adafruit.com/products/157

---

There is a guide at http://www.weedpi.com/how-to/add-ir-support-to-your-raspberry-pi/ that is very basic and easy to follow, and will walk you through setting up `LIRC`, recording an input from any remote, and assigning a command to be run (like `raspistill -o cam.jpg` for example) when the `LIRC daemon` sees reads that command from the sensor.

---

There are tons of other walkthroughs online, though not all of them specifically address Raspbery Pi. Once you get through this first one, you should be able to create more complicated configurations.